# Does praying four rakaats before and after zuhr make the fire of Hell haram?

Tags: salat, hadith-interpretation

I have read this from somewhere but want to know if this is true or not?
Looking for answers from the Sunni perspective.

> Virtues of the Four Rak'aah Sunnah of Zuhr
>
> The Prophet (sallallahu alaiyhi wassallam) is reported to have said that Whoever performs the four rakaats before and after the Zuhr salat with constancy, Allah Ta'ala makes the fire of Hell haram (forbidden) for him. [Mishkat, p. 104; Tirmizi, Abu Da'ud, Nisai, Ibn Majah]

Is this true??

Also when they refer to 4 rakaats before and after, what do they mean? 4 rakaat of Sunnah before the Fard? (i.e 4x4x2x2) and what do they mean 4 rakaat after?

Source: http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?239056-VERY-Rewarding-Nafl-Salaahs-we-can-Pray-Everyday!

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/offer-all-sunnah-before-farz

Comment: So what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: @Medi1Saif - brother, what i have said in the question. - IS IT TRUE that that the salah of 4 Rakaah Sunnah of Zuhr makes hellfire haram for a Muslim?

Comment: If you believe it yes, if not no ... would be my first draft. What i want to say hadith is in Arabic language and therefore it might include some exaggeration or emphasize or ... What this hadith may mean is if you do this every and never stop you might be a good step away from hellfire! As the most important things that count in the hereafter is not our worship rather than our behavior towards others, as even if we might have worshiped Allah much we may be punished if we were bad to others. You shouldn't take it literally! Note I said "may" as my comment is not a well elaborated answer!

Comment: hmmm ok - thanks. I would however like a full correct answer, with backup! :)

Comment: See for example my answer on this question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33267/how-do-i-know-my-ramadan-is-accepted if that doesn't help then maybe I'll try to check a commentary of Jami' at-Tirmdihi. Until then please also check those similar ahadith http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89+%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B9+%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA+%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B8%D9%87%D8%B1+%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B9+%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%87%D8%A7