# Will my non-obligatory prayer be accepted if I had the intention not to pray if something occurs?

Tags: salat

I used pay two rakat after Magrib (we call it NAFILA but I don't know if this it actual name in Arabic). However, yesterday I had the intention not to pray these two rakat if after magrib the restaurant is opened (mostly because after a few minutes the restaurant can be full). I had the intention to let these two rakat for eating. After the prayer is done, the restaurant was not open, so I stayed in the mosque and prayed the two rakats.

My Question is: Will my prayer be accepted??

Comment: I'd give the same anaswer as here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33267/how-do-i-know-my-ramadan-is-accepted

Comment: @Medi1Saif, the link you gave taught me something new but I do not see a close relation between he's question and mine. I did the prayer but I had intention not to pray.

Comment: Well it is not to us to give an answer of something Allah only knows about. Technically your prayer is valid.

Comment: Now I want to know if I was wrong in the word `Nafila`. I am from burkina faso, there, we call these prayers `Nafila` (2 prayers after Dhuhr, Magrib, 3 after Isha.). I want to know if it is the right word in arabic.

Comment: You may call it nafila or sunnah or what ever it is an optional prayer that is what counts. Scholars called nafl prayers like that as-sunan ar-rawatib (sunnah prayers related to some fard prayers)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take our  2min. [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about this site and model.  @Medi1Saif maybe you should think of posting an answer of the question instead of answering it via comments http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/answers-on-comment-section.

Answer (score 1):

You start getting reward of a good deed from time you have its intention.

First your intention was to not pray nafil if restaurant was open, during that time you was not getting reward of intention of a good deed.

But after salah when you saw restaurant was closed and you started the nafil prayer with intention, then you got its reward and InshaAllah it was accepted.

For future always have intention that you will do any good deed, even if later due to some factor you decide not to do it or you could not do it, at least you will have reward for your intentions till that time.