# Sequence of fard and sunnah salaah

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunnah, fard

As-salaam aleykum wa rahamatullah wa barkatahu.

Can I change the sequence of sunnah and fard salaah? For example, if I am waiting for the congregation / jamaat for zohar fard can I offer 4 raqat sunnah which is supposed to precede the fard and also read the 2 raqat sunnah which is supposed to follow the fard, before the congreation fard salaah since I have time for it.

As-salaam aleykum wa rahamatullah wa barkatahu.
Mohammed Eliyas.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No you can't, but you can use the time to pray any nafl or recite the Qur'an.

Allah told us:

> ... prayer has been decreed upon the believers a decree of specified times. ([5:103](http://legacy.quran.com/4/103))

So if you want to pray those sunnah porayers which are considered as sunnah muakadah by many madhhabs and are related to specific fard prayers (also called as-sunan ar-Rwatib) you can't pray them before or after their time (the later unless you've missed it as qada' according to some madhhabs). See also [What are Sunnah Rawaatib?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38134/what-are-sunnah-rawaatib).

But none can hinder you to pray any nafl prayer at any time unless it is a time of karaha (where praying optional prayers is frowned upon like after sunrise and right before sunset etc.).

Other related posts:
[Time of reading Sunnah prayer before the fard prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34948/time-of-reading-sunnah-prayer-before-the-fard-prayer/34952#34952)
[Offer all sunnah before farz](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/offer-all-sunnah-before-farz/28575#28575)
[How many raka'ats of salat is to be recited before 4 raka'ats of farz of zuhr salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35459/how-many-rakaats-of-salat-is-to-be-recited-before-4-rakaats-of-farz-of-zuhr-sa/46911#46911)